# Readiness probe failing for pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a simple pod and has readiness probe configured. All it is doing is checking for the service running at a NodePort 30080. When I run the pod it fails due to readiness check:-

```
Readiness probe failed: Connecting to localhost:30080 (127.0.0.1:30080)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

I can curl the pod and get the response back.

```
curl http://localhost:30080
```

If I use the same command in the readiness probe I get the error. Following is the deployment descriptor. Any assistance would be of great help.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: nginx:1.16.1-alpine
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command: ["wget", "-T2", "-O-", "http://localhost:30080"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 1
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
```

Comment: NodePort is outside the container. A readinessProbe is meant to check the status of the container in the Pod. What are you trying to do? Does your pod listen to any port? Can that port be used as ReadinessProbe?

Comment: @Jonas My new deployment descriptor with readinessProbe now executes a wget on pod which has port 8080 configured.

8080 is the pod port
30080 is the node port
8080 is the target port

With readiness I am trying to check if a pod running on a 8080 port is accessible. Since pod is exposed via service I am trying to wget service . I tried 8080 of pod, 8080 of service and 30080 of service node port. None of it works with readiness. I can wget service from curl from the terminal and get a response back.

Answer (score 0):

The command of the `readinessProbe` is executed inside of the container, so you need to specify the port that your nginx is running on. It is the same as the target port of your Service. Here is the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/):

> To perform a probe, the kubelet executes the command ... in the target container.

Comment: I am seeing same error even if I change the port to port of service

Warning  Unhealthy  5s    kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Connecting to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

> 8080 is the pod port

> With readiness I am trying to check if a pod running on a 8080 port is accessible.

With this info, you can configure a **ReadinessProbe** like e.g.:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /my-path
    port: 8080
```

> Since pod is exposed via service I am trying to wget service

Your ReadinessProbe should be for the Pod, not the Service. Multiple pods will be behind a Service, e.g. during a new deployment. It is important that the ReadinessProbe only checks a single replica - not all behind a Service.

Comment: Is this the preferred approach of checking a single pod in a readiness probe than a service for accessibility of an application? In a prod scenario it can be possible that a specific pod may run in to issue but other replicas may continue to serve.

Comment: @JamesStan yes, your last sentence is the point with ReadinessProbe - to check that the specific Replica is ready to handle traffic. It is most useful during deployment, while your Replica starts up and does initialization before it is ready to serve customer traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the correct syntax to ping a Node port service as part of readiness probe.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: nginx:1.16.1-alpine
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 32044
        host: "localhost"
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 1
      successThreshold: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
```